# google script scrape parser with 2 classes with the same name

Tags: google-apps-script, html-parsing

I am looking to build a scraper in google scripts. There are 2 classe with the same name and I can't find a way to get the second class. It only outputs the first one.

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = "https://www.zchocolat.com/shop/fr/livraison-cadeau-chocolat/espagne";
    var fromText = '<p class="article"';
    var toText = '">';

    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var scraped = Parser
                .data(content)
                .setLog()
                .from(fromText)
                .to(toText)
                .build();
    Logger.log(scraped);
    return scraped;
}

function SAVE_DATA() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('Feuille 1'); 
   sheet.appendRow([ new Date(), myFunction() ]);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this sample?

### Modification points :

1. When it sees the `Parser` of library you use at [here](https://script.google.com/d/1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw/edit?usp=drive_web), it seems that by using `iterate()`, data can be retrieved as an array.
2. The data you want is second one.

When these are reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.zchocolat.com/shop/fr/livraison-cadeau-chocolat/espagne";
  var fromText = '<p class="article">';
  var toText = '</p>';
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var scraped = Parser
              .data(content)
              .from(fromText)
              .to(toText)
              .iterate();
  Logger.log(scraped[1]);
  return scraped;
}
```

#### Result :

```
97% de nos colis ont &eacute;t&eacute; livr&eacute;s dans les temps en 2016.
                                        zChocolat a d&eacute;j&agrave; livr&eacute; avec succ&egrave;s 21,923 cadeaux chocolat en Espagne.
```

Answer (score 3):

You should parse the html with the XmlService so that you can more easily extract the nodes you want. There are some good examples at this site (https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html)

You would end up with something like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = "https://www.zchocolat.com/shop/fr/livraison-cadeau-chocolat/espagne";
    var fromText = '<p class="article"';
    var toText = '">';

    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
    var html = doc.getRootElement();
    var articles = getElementsByClassName(html, 'articles');
    Logger.log(articles);
}

function getElementsByClassName(element, classToFind) {  
  var data = [];
  var descendants = element.getDescendants();
  descendants.push(element);  
  for(i in descendants) {
    var elt = descendants[i].asElement();
    if(elt != null) {
      var classes = elt.getAttribute('class');
      if(classes != null) {
        classes = classes.getValue();
        if(classes == classToFind) data.push(elt);
        else {
          classes = classes.split(' ');
          for(j in classes) {
            if(classes[j] == classToFind) {
              data.push(elt);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in your method. I have one question for your answer. May I ask you it?

Comment: Sure. It is a method I found on the site that I linked. What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried your script. But it didn't work. Error is ``Error: Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`` at ``var doc = XmlService.parse(content);``. I would like to know how to parse ``var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.zchocolat.com/shop/fr/livraison-cadeau-chocolat/espagne").getContentText();`` by XmlService.

Comment: Could you understand my question?

Comment: Can you post all of your code? I can't figure out what your error is saying without seeing all of it

Comment: Script I use is basically same to yours. I modified this ``var doc = XmlService.parse(html);``. I did ``html`` to ``content``. Error message is in my comment. Can you update your script to working one?

Comment: I showed my script as per your request. You got it?